# How to run project which depends on library in Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I have two project in Eclipse for Android. One is library and second is normal "executable", which depends on library. But the problem is, when I'm editing source files from the library, I make my changes and I want to try it, Eclipse say that "Android library project could not be run", so I have to manually switch to some source file from "executable" project and then run it. It's driving me nuts, 80% editing of source code is in library. In earlier version of Android SDK, there was a link to library source, but in release 16 they remove that link. I can make that link manually, but then the changes I make, doesn't seems to take effect, unless I change one the "executable" source fles. Please help!

Comment: I'm with you on this. Drives me crazy having to do that exact thing. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

the following works for me: in following Eclipse preferences

*Run/Debug->Launching->Launch Options*

choose either

*Always launch the previously launched application*

or

*Launch the selected resource or active editor. If not launchable: Launch the previous launched application.*

--
P

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [Setting up a Library Project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject) guide. Setting the project as library works fine with SDK Rev.16

Comment: I know how to setup it. It works fin, but my question was, how to simply debug it (by pressing one key, not two click and one key) while i'm editing file from library.

Comment: Well, why don't you use recent launches then? Just to be on the same side: you press the arrow at the left of "run" button and see recent launches. Actually this is already enough to run your "executable" project: you just select it from this list. Moreover, you may add it to favorites with "Organize Favorites..." item.

Comment: Yes, this is fine solution, but I always have to grab the mouse. Is there any possibility how to lunch it whitout grabing the mouse, but by pressing just ONE key?